# Adjust iOS TabBar item title to the centre of it

Tags: ios

```
//TabBarController code:

self.delegate=self;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.delegate=self;

CGRect viewFrame=self.tabBar.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y -=0;![enter image description here][1]
viewFrame.origin.x -=0;
viewFrame.size.height=30;
self.tabBar.frame=viewFrame;

firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];

NSArray *twoViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                       self.firstViewController, self.secondViewController, nil];

self.viewControllers=twoViewControllers;



//    ====================================================
//    
//    FirstViewController code in initWithNibName: 
//    
//    To set the title of the first tabbar item:


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Article view";
        NSLog(@"count = %d",[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items count]);

    }
    return self;
}
```

//How can i make the first tabbar item title "Article View" to the Center without adding any //image to the tabbaritem ?

//    similar to the below tabbar items screenshot.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBpVH.png


Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace the `initWithNibName` method

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Article view";
        self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);
        NSLog(@"count = %d",[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items count]);
    }
    return self;
}
```

`self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);` this line here adjusts the position of the image for the tabBarItem in the manner :

> Shift the image in x-direction '+5' and in y-direction '-5' from the
>   default position.

Play with `UIEdgeInsetsMake` and have fun. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for helping me dude..

I asked you instead of working on image, Rather I should change the position of the title and it got fixed.

Comment: glad i could help ..give the answer a check if u feel like ;) :)